# Создание очереди на основе двунаправленного списка

Tags: c++, очередь

Объявил указатели на начало и конец очереди, вопрос следующий, как вообще определяется что один указатель есть начало очереди, а второй ее конец?.
Попробовал распечатать очередь, ничего не вышло, но ошибки при создании очереди нет.

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
//------------------------------------------------------------------
struct Double_List {//структура данных
    int Data; //информационное поле
    Double_List* Next, //адресное поле
        * Prior; //адресное поле
};

//создание двунаправленного списка (добавления в конец)
void Make_Double_List(int n, Double_List** Head,
    Double_List* Prior) {
    if (n > 0) {
        (*Head) = new Double_List();
        //выделяем память под новый элемент
        cout << "Введите значение ";
        cin >> (*Head)->Data;
        //вводим значение информационного поля
        (*Head)->Prior = Prior;
        (*Head)->Next = NULL;//обнуление адресного поля
        Make_Double_List(n - 1, &((*Head)->Next), (*Head));
    }
    else (*Head) = NULL;
}


//печать двунаправленного списка
void Print_Double_List(Double_List* Head) {
    if (Head != NULL) {
        cout << Head->Data << "\t";
        Print_Double_List(Head->Next);
        //переход к следующему элементу
    }
    else cout << "\n";
}


//вставка элемента с заданным номером в двунаправленный список
Double_List* Insert_Item_Double_List(Double_List* Head,
    int Number, int DataItem) {
    Number--;
    Double_List* NewItem = new(Double_List);
    NewItem->Data = DataItem;
    NewItem->Prior = NULL;
    NewItem->Next = NULL;
    if (Head == NULL) {//список пуст
        Head = NewItem;
    }
    else {//список не пуст
        Double_List* Current = Head;
        for (int i = 1; i < Number && Current->Next != NULL; i++)
            Current = Current->Next;
        if (Number == 0) {
            //вставляем новый элемент на первое место
            NewItem->Next = Head;
            Head->Prior = NewItem;
            Head = NewItem;
        }
        else {//вставляем новый элемент на непервое место
            if (Current->Next != NULL) Current->Next->Prior = NewItem;
            NewItem->Next = Current->Next;
            Current->Next = NewItem;
            NewItem->Prior = Current;
            Current = NewItem;
        }
    }
    return Head;
}


/*удаление элемента с заданным номером из двунаправленного списка*/
Double_List* Delete_Item_Double_List(Double_List* Head,
    int Number) {
    Double_List* ptr;//вспомогательный указатель
    Double_List* Current = Head;
    for (int i = 1; i < Number && Current != NULL; i++)
        Current = Current->Next;
    if (Current != NULL) {//проверка на корректность
        if (Current->Prior == NULL) {//удаляем первый элемент
            Head = Head->Next;
            delete(Current);
            if (Head != 0) Head->Prior = NULL;
            Current = Head;
        }
        else {//удаляем непервый элемент
            if (Current->Next == NULL) {
                //удаляем последний элемент
                Current->Prior->Next = NULL;
                delete(Current);
                Current = Head;
            }
            else {//удаляем непервый и непоследний элемент
                ptr = Current->Next;
                Current->Prior->Next = Current->Next;
                Current->Next->Prior = Current->Prior;
                delete(Current);
                Current = ptr;
            }
        }
    }
    return Head;
}

//освобождение памяти, выделенной под двунаправленный список
void Delete_Double_List(Double_List* Head) {
    if (Head != NULL) {
        Delete_Double_List(Head->Next);
        delete Head;
    }
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
struct Queue {
    Double_List* Begin;//начало очереди
    Double_List* End; //конец очереди
};
Queue* My_Queue;//указатель на очередь
//создание очереди
void Make_Queue(int n, Queue* End_Queue) {
    Make_Double_List(n, &(End_Queue->Begin), NULL);
    Double_List* ptr; //вспомогательный указатель
    ptr = End_Queue->Begin;
    while (ptr->Next != NULL)
        ptr = ptr->Next;
    End_Queue->End = ptr;
}

//проверка пустоты двунаправленого списка
bool Empty_Double_List(Double_List* Head) {
    if (Head != NULL) return false;
    else return true;
}
//печать очереди
void Print_Queue(Queue* Begin_Queue) {
    Print_Double_List(Begin_Queue->Begin);
}

//добавление элемента в конец очереди
void Add_Item_Queue(int NewElem, Queue* End_Queue) {
    End_Queue->End = Insert_Item_Double_List(End_Queue->End,
        0, NewElem)->Next;
}
//извлечение элемента из начала очереди
int Extract_Item_Queue(Queue* Begin_Queue) {
    int NewElem = NULL;
    if (Begin_Queue->Begin != NULL) {
        NewElem = Begin_Queue->Begin->Data;
        Begin_Queue->Begin = Delete_Item_Double_List(Begin_Queue->Begin, 0);
        //удаляем вершину
    }
    return NewElem;
}
//проверка пустоты очереди
bool Empty_Queue(Queue* Begin_Queue) {
    return Empty_Double_List(Begin_Queue->Begin);
}
//очистка очереди
void Clear_Queue(Queue* Begin_Queue) {
    return Delete_Double_List(Begin_Queue->Begin);
}
//функция поиска первого наибольшего отрицательного элемента
int Find_Max_Negative_Element(Queue* Begin_Queue) {
    int tmp;
    int max = Extract_Item_Queue(Begin_Queue);
    while (Begin_Queue->Begin->Data != 0) {
        tmp = Extract_Item_Queue(Begin_Queue);
        if (max < tmp) 
        {
            max = tmp;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
int main()
{
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
Queue* My_Queue = new Queue();
Queue* End_Queue = new Queue();
Queue* Begin_Queue = new Queue();
Make_Queue(4, End_Queue);
Print_Queue(Begin_Queue);
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: [посмотрите](https://ci-plus-plus-snachala.ru/?p=60) сначала, как пишут код другие с помощью классов. все коротко и понятно. не нужна простыня из сишных методов (либо в условиях пишите, что с++ не хотите, а хотите на си). во-вторых, пользуйтесь отладчиком, смотрите что происходит при добавлении элемента и т.д.

Comment: Это учебный код, его идея в том чтобы изучить более приближенно к низкому уровню, насколько я понял. Поэтому скорее всего как вы сказали используются C методы. Разве использование методов больше относится к C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не объявили указатели на начало и конец очереди. Вы создали 3 экземпляра Queue. Заполнили очередь с именем End_Queue элементами, а потом пытаетесь распечатать другую очередь с именем Begin_Queue. Вы зачем-то создаете эти элементы в куче и в конце программы не освобождаете память, которую под них выделили.
Указатели на начало и конец очереди определяются вами, вручную, в соответствии с логикой вашей программы. И вам нужно поддерживать механику обновления этих указателей по ходу вашей программы. Эти указатели по логике вашей программы хранятся в объекте класса (структуры) Queue. Вам нужен один экземпляр Queue. И при изменении начала или конца очереди вносить изменения в значения указателей в этом объекте.
И тогда передавать в функции ссылку или указатель на этот объект.

```
void Print_Queue(Queue& MyQueue) {
    Print_Double_List(MyQueue.Begin);
}

void Make_Queue(int n, Queue& MyQueue) {
}

int main()
{
  Queue MyQueue;
  MyQueue.Begin = nullptr;
  Make_Queue(4, MyQueue);
}
```

Для ускорения некоторых операций можно хранить в очереди дополнительные данные - например текущий размер очереди.
Еще один момент - не используйте рекурсии функций там, где можно обойтись простым циклом. Рекурсии дольше работают и при больших размерах данных вы получите переполнение стека.

```
void Print_Double_List(Double_List* ptr) {
    while(ptr != NULL) {
        cout << ptr->Data << "\t";
        //переход к следующему элементу
        //Print_Double_List(Head->Next); - рекурсия не нужна!!!
        ptr = ptr->Next;
    }
    else cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое.